# Trying to convert frames into videos from multiple folder with subfolders

Tags: python, opencv

I have a root folders which contains multiple folders some with the png inside some with sub-folders and png inside.

My code:

```
import os
import cv2

root = r'C:\Users\sboroghina\Documents\_projects\json_compare'



for videopath, videodirs, videofiles in os.walk(root, topdown=False):
    for videoname in videodirs:
        if len(videoname) > 40:
            video_name = str(videoname) + '.avi'


            for path, dirs, files in os.walk(root, topdown=False):
                image_folder = path
                images = [f for f in os.listdir(image_folder) if f.endswith('.png')]
                frame = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, images[0]))
                height, width, layers = frame.shape
                video = cv2.VideoWriter(video_name, 0, 30, (width, height))


                for image in images:
                    video.write(cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, image)))
                    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                    video.release()
```

I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sboroghina\Documents\_projects\generate_annotation_images\test2.py", line 20, in <module>
    frame = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, images[0]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't understand why it gives me this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined the `images` variable like so:

```
images = [f for f in os.listdir(image_folder) if f.endswith('.png')]
```

afterwards, without any validation, you did:

```
images[0]
```

Now, this can cause problems for cases when `images` is an empty list, meaning none of the listed files in `os.listdir(image_folder)` ends with a `".png'`.

Simply change this block of code:

```
            for path, dirs, files in os.walk(root, topdown=False):
                image_folder = path
                images = [f for f in os.listdir(image_folder) if f.endswith('.png')]
                frame = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, images[0]))
                height, width, layers = frame.shape
                video = cv2.VideoWriter(video_name, 0, 30, (width, height))

                for image in images:
                    video.write(cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, image)))
                    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                    video.release()
```

to:

```
            for path, dirs, files in os.walk(root, topdown=False):
                image_folder = path
                images = [f for f in os.listdir(image_folder) if f.endswith('.png')]
                if images: # Validation
                    frame = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, images[0]))
                    height, width, layers = frame.shape
                    video = cv2.VideoWriter(video_name, 0, 30, (width, height))

                    for image in images:
                        video.write(cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, image)))
                    cv2.destroyAllWindows() # Unindented
                    video.release()
```

Note that I've also unindented those lines once:

```
                    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                    video.release()
```

so that the `VideoWriter` object doesn't get released until after all the frames are written in.

Comment: Works perfectly and I understood what I was doing wrong so thank you for you help and explanation.